# How to upgrade from Windows 7 x86 to Windows 7 x64?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, upgrade, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When reinstalling Windows 7, does the language, version, architecture (64-bit or 32-bit) or source (OEM, retail, or MSDN) matter?](https://superuser.com/questions/303136/when-reinstalling-windows-7-does-the-language-version-architecture-64-bit-or)

I want to move up to Win7 64 bit from Win7 32 bit.

What is best way to do this?

Answer (score 10):

The [32-bit and 64-bit Windows FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/32-bit-and-64-bit-Windows-frequently-asked-questions) states:

> If you want to move from a 32-bit version of Windows to a 64-bit version of Windows Vista or vice versa, you'll need to back up your files and then choose the Custom option during Windows Vista installation. Then, you'll need to restore your files and reinstall your programs.

Thus make a back-up if you want to and then reinstall, there is no other feasible way...

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, switching from 32 bit to 64 bit, or vise versa, cannot be done as an in-place upgrade. Even if it's the same operating system. You need to back up your files and programs and do the whole install.

Answer (score 1):

The 32bit to 64bit conversion makes fundamental changes to the way your system runs that can't be done on a running system.  You will have to re-install windows and everything that goes along with that.