# process to upgrade a computer from Win 7 x86 to Win 7 x64?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to upgrade from Windows 7 x86 to Windows 7 x64?](https://superuser.com/questions/167509/how-to-upgrade-from-windows-7-x86-to-windows-7-x64)

What's the [best] process to upgrade a computer from Win 7 x86 to Win 7 x64?

Comment: Duplicate question, see my answer: http://superuser.com/questions/167509/how-to-upgrade-from-windows-7-x86-to-windows-7-x64/167510#167510

Answer (score 1):

While there is no direct upgrade path across architectures, you can use Windows Easy Transfer on the 32-bit machine to transfer all of your files and settings to the 64-bit machine.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove old 32bit and install new 64bit version of Windows 7 in your system.